# CMake Toolchain File for GHS

Tags: cmake, greenhills

I am trying to create a cmake toolchain file for the GreenHills compiler.
When I am using `cmake -T C:\ghs\multi506` everything works fine.
But after creating a toolchain file with the line
`set(GHS_TOOLSET_ROOT C:/ghs/multi506)` I get the error message:

> CMake Error: No GHS toolsets found in GHS_TOOLSET_ROOT "C:/ghs/multi506/"

What is the problem?

Comment: For CMake / GHS questions you should probably try https://discourse.cmake.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `-T` and `GHS_TOOLSET_ROOT` is finicky.  This is because of trying to maintain backward compatibility with the original generator implementation of trying to find the "latest" compiler.

'-T' takes either a absolute path or a relative path.

`-T C:\ghs\multi506` means that the compilers are in this directory.  It will contain gbuild.exe, etcetera.

`-T multi506` will append `multi506` to `GHS_TOOLSET_ROOT`. Therefore `CMake` will look for `gbuild.exe` in `C:\ghs\multi506`.

If you don't use `-T` then auto search mode is enabled. `CMake` will search for directories named `comp_[^;]+`, which is the naming scheme Green Hills uses for its compilers, in `GHS_TOOLSET_ROOT`. So in this case it will be looking for something like `C:\ghs\multi506\comp_20210504`.

I prefer using `-T` with an absolute path to the compiler directory.